# Setting std::shared_ptr to point on reference

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference, shared-ptr

```
class a
{
private:
  std::shared_ptr <std::string> sptr;
public:
  void set(std::string & ref)
  {
   sptr = &ref; //error
  }
};
```

What's the solution? I need to keep the reference as the argument and I need the private pointer to be shared_ptr.

Comment: @Kerrek SB thank you. You can make an answer with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To assign a new raw pointer to a shared pointer and make the shared pointer take ownership, use the member function `reset`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> p;

p.reset(new Foo);
```

The shared pointer *shares ownership* of the object, so it's almost impossible to have your `sptr` share ownership sensibly on an arbitrary reference. (E.g. `sptr.reset(&ref)` would almost certainly be com­pletely wrong.) The appropriate thing to do is to make a new copy of the string, i.e. either `sptr.reset(new std::string(ref))`, or better:

```
sptr = std::make_shared<std::string>(ref);
```

Comment: And if it's not a `std::string` but a custom class you can change, consider [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: @ArneMertz: Yeah, but that's fairly subtle and specialized. You'd have to design the class entirely for being owned by a shared pointer from the start. When appropriate that's a good idea, though!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store address of your reference then you can use

```
sptr = std::shared_ptr<std::string>(&ref, [](const std::string*){});
```

Else if you want to store new object - use Kerrek SB variant.

Comment: This works, but it imposes a crucial unwritten and non-local assumption, namely that the reference outlive all copies of the `a` object.

Comment: `shared_ptr` becomes fairly useless without a deleter. It's just a non-owning reference (what raw pointer should be used for). The only thing it provides is that weak_ptrs can check if the object still exists, but if they lock they don't actually extend lifetime. Nobody extends lifetime.